# Create UITableView with multiple Custom Cells in Swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

What is the best current way to create an `UITableView` with multiples Custom Cell with the storyboard and the tableView methods?

For now, I get correctly my `JSON` response split into 3 arrays then I want to use it to update my tableView with 3 different custom cells.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    var starters = [Starter]()
    var dishes = [Dish]()
    var deserts = [Desert]()

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var foodTableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - Functions
    func updatDisplay() {
        ApiHelper.getFoods { starters, dishes, deserts in
            self.starters = starters
            self.dishes = dishes
            self.deserts = deserts
            self.foodTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updatDisplay()
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StarterCell", for: indexPath)

        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: how you want to differentiate cells?? on what basis??

Comment: do you want to have a section for each of the types of cells, or what type of ordering do you want to apply to them?

Comment: I want one custom cell for each array (starters,  dishes, deserts).

Comment: Yes, I  want a section for each of the types of cells.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have the three sections "starters", "dishes" and "deserts" you can display the cells like this:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return starters.count
    }
    else if section == 1 {
        return dishes.count
    }
    else {
        return deserts.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return "Starters"
    }
    else if section == 1 {
        return "Dishes"
    }
    else {
        return "Deserts"
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StarterCell", for: indexPath)
    }
    else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DishesCell", for: indexPath)
    }
    else {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DesertsCell", for: indexPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you register the cells programatically?